# Unable to locate element by id - error

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm using selenium webdriver to click on two check boxes.

I used the Xpath and ID to click. But I get this error : `Unable to locate element`

```
table id="checkboxfield-1321" class="x-field x-form-item x-field-default x-anchor-form-item" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: auto;"

table id="checkboxfield-1322" class="x-field x-form-item x-field-default x-anchor-form-item" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout: auto;"
```

Comment: What is the html of the page and what xpath did you try?

Comment: It worked for me when I called the parent element and tried to click the sibling.

Answer (score 0):

css=table.x-anchor-form-item:nth-of-type(1) input -- CSS Selector of Check Box 1

css=table.x-anchor-form-item:nth-of-type(2) input -- CSS Selector of Check Box 2

Please Let me know Is the above CSS Selectors are working or Not.